# Why can I not TTY into the node:17-alpine image the way I can the NGINX one?

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

I have the following yml...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: simple-server 
  labels:
    run: simple-server
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
```

Once applied I can access a bash shell like `sudo kubectl exec --stdin --tty simple-server -- /bin/bash`. I have a simple Koa docker image I created from `node:17-alpine` like this...

```
FROM node:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD node server.mjs

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: simple-server-node
  labels:
    run: simple-server-node
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: partyk1d24/node-k8s-demo
      ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

This one deploys and I can access it using a service. However, when I try to open a tty bash shell I get...

> node % sudo kubectl exec --stdin --tty pod/simple-server-node --
> /bin/bash OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown
> command terminated with exit code 126

Why can't I open a shell in the node image the same way I can in the nginx one?

Comment: "*Why can't I open a shell in the node image the same way I can in the nginx one?*" - Because alpine does not come with bash installed. We can, however, use `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as answer for better visibility.

"Why can't I open a shell in the node image the same way I can in the nginx one?" - Because alpine does not come with bash installed. We can, however, use /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash.